# Etymology of the word "šowhar" in Persian

Tags: etymology

I am looking for etymology of the word شوهر in Persian language, I looked in wiktionary and two other dictionaries but found nothing.

šowhar means "husband" in modern persian.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D9%88%D9%87%D8%B1?oldid=49026403

Answer (score 3):

The Persian word has cognates in many IE languages, most meaning father-in-law or brother-in-law: German Schwager, Gothic swaihra, Latin socer, Greek `εκυρός, Sanskrit śvaśura-s, Russian свёкор, Lithuanian šešuras, Welsh chwegr, Albanian vjehërr, Armenian skesrayr

See Pokorny’s entry for [su̯ekrū́-](https://indo-european.info/pokorny-etymological-dictionary/whnjs.htm) .

Answer (score 2):

Persian šōhar (šawhar) seems to imply Iranian *xšawdar-, and the parallel form šōy would be from the nominative *xšawdā, presumably an actor noun from the verbal stem *xšawd- “to wash, to become liquid”, as in Persian šustan, šōy- “to wash”, or Avestan xšudra- “fluid, semen”.

Comment: I looked up Ger *schütten* "to pour" because of "xšudra- “fluid, semen”", and found Low German *schütten* "protect" (Ger *schützen*), which I immediately recognized. If I may refer to *house*, PIE \*(s)kew-s-, PIE \*(s)kew- "cover, hide" (that is "protect"), vs. *house-band*. However obvious the parallel may be, it's not recognized in *husband* anymore, might not have been in *showhar*, and perhaps was not original either, even if *legal guardian* is still a connotation in living memory. Linking "[expended] fluid" maybe difficult, but seeing these as completely unrelated would be short-sighted

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I didn't understand the difference between *xšawdar and *xšawda, are they PIE roots of šôhar and šôy respectively and is šoy then only a diminutive of šowhar? What's the exact function of adding a -r suffix ?

Comment: And also could you give sources or links to this findings? I couldn't find a serious and complete etymological dictionnary for Persian.

Comment: @fdb and also, I found out this about šustan : The formal and literary present/imperfective stem of šustan isشوی‎ (šuy), but in colloquial speech, شور‎ (šur) is more common. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%86?oldid=45620967

Comment: @user25137. Indo-Iranian has nominative singular pitā “father” but forms all the other cases from pitar- (full grade) of pitr- (zero grade). The -r is lost only in the long-grade nominative singular. The words for “mother”, “brother”, “husband” and a few others work the same way.

Comment: @fdb ok I see, thank you for taking time for quick answer. What about sources, did you find out this by yourself or do you have any source ? If yes can you share them with us/me ?

Comment: @user25137. The connection between šōhar and xšudra- goes back at least to Horn. See also (somewhat differently) Hübschmann, Persische Studien (1895), p. 82.

Comment: @fdb I see, big up to you. *xšawd is a PIE word that gave birth to Avestan xšudra and Persian šustan. Do you know if it has any other cognate in other IE languages ?

Comment: @user25137 Sanskrit kṣodas- “flowing water”.